# Get items in current page from ASP .NET PagedDataSource

Tags: asp.net, pagination, paging

I am implementing paging on a custom server control, and I'm wondering if I can use the PagedDataSource to my advantage. Is there a way to get the items just from the current page of the PagedDataSource? Will this work to do this?

```
For Each item As Object In pagedDataSource
```

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and tried this, and this does work. As long as you set up the PagedDataSource correctly (set AllowPaging, PageSize, and CurrentPageIndex, and, of course, DataSource), then you can use

```
For Each item As Object In pagedDataSource
```

to iterate through the current page of items.